# Azure Terraform: dynamically add network IDs as resolution networks to private DNS zone

Tags: azure, terraform

I am working on a complicated terraform template which breaks our products into separate modules so that we can build our infrastructure (or add on to it) modularly.

We will have a root virtual network that contains a DNS private zone. This zone will obviously only have a resolution network of the root network.

The next product will create a new virtual network in a different subscription, then the networks will be peered and I want to add that new network id to the resolution list of the DNS zone.

There doesnt seem to be an additive function to referencing and updating a resource in Terraform so I had been stuck essentially trying to create it again with the new list of resolution networks. Is there a better way?

Doing the new resource seems to want to delete the old.

Answer (score 0):

They are working on adding a new resource type to the azurerm terraform provider: *azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link*. This will allow adding resolution and registration networks to private dns zones without using the *azurerm_private_dns_zone* resource type. It will be available in the upcoming Azure Terraform provider 2.0.

I have not found a workaround to use until then.

More details on the upcoming funtion from the corresponding [pull request](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/3789):

> **azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link**
>   Enables you to manage
>   Private DNS zone Virtual Network Links. These Links enable DNS
>   resolution and registration inside Azure Virtual Networks using Azure
>   Private DNS.
>
> **Example Usage**
>
> ```
> resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
>   name     = "acceptanceTestResourceGroup1"
>   location = "West US"
> }
>
> resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "test" {
>   name                = "mydomain.com"
>   resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
> }
>
> resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "test" {
>   name                  = "test"
>   resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
>   private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.test.name
>   virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.test.id
> }
> ```
>
> **Argument Reference**
>
> The following arguments are supported:
>
> *name* - (Required) The name of the Private DNS Zone Virtual Network
>   Link. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.
>
> *private_dns_zone_name* - (Required) The name of the Private DNS zone
>   (without a terminating dot). Changing this forces a new resource to be
>   created.
>
> *virtual_network_id* - (Required) The Resource ID of the Virtual Network
>   that should be linked to the DNS Zone. Changing this forces a new
>   resource to be created.
>
> *registration_enabled* - (Optional) Is auto-registration of virtual
>   machine records in the virtual network in the Private DNS zone
>   enabled? Defaults to false.
>
> *resource_group_name* - (Required) Specifies the resource group where
>   the resource exists. Changing this forces a new resource to be
>   created.
>
> *tags* - (Optional) A mapping of tags to assign to the resource.